# Name of a short story with a telepathic man and cats

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, I read a short story where a telepathic man suddenly realizes he can read the thoughts of cats. He discovers that instead of being dumb animals, cats have secretly been manipulating humans all along. The cats realize that he's discovered their plans, and the short story ends with one of them tripping the man off the boarding ramp of a spaceship and he dies.

Does anyone know what short story book this might be from or which author?

Comment: Could you tell some more out-of-character details?  For example, can you remember how old the story could have been, or something about the collection where it was published, the style, or in what language you have read it?

Comment: I don't really remember much else. It was in English, and I read it about 10 years ago. The book seemed old then, but that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the man isn't from earth, he is from another planet.  He visits Earth and finds out that he can read the minds of Dogs, not cats, and that they rule the world by sucking up to men.  He is trying to warn the his fellows about it (they have been given a breeding pair of dogs as a gift to take back with them).  They think he's nuts, and yes, a dog does trip him and he falls out of the spaceship and dies.

It is a short story by Eric Frank Russell "[Into Your Tent I'll Creep](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2228091.Into_Your_Tent_I_ll_Creep)".  Collected in the "Best of Eric Frank Russell".

Comment: `+1` for you username...

Comment: Cats have been openly manipulating humans all along.

Comment: that's fantastic! i've been misremembering all this time, but it does make more sense for it to have been dogs.