# A short story about humans becoming pets and pets caring for them

Tags: story-identification, animals

The story is rather short - one or two A4 pages, and I read it in a weekly (not in English) some 30-33 years ago.

The setting is a room, with a man and a pet (either a cat or a dog). The pet starts speaking and the man is taken aback, because the pet explains that humanity has run its course, and will degrade mentally to the point of not being able to take care of itself. The story concludes with the pet saying that the man shouldn't be afraid or worried, because the pet will take good care of him.

As far as I can tell, there was no uplifting, telepathy or magic involved.

Comment: Similar, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92491/what-classic-sf-story-involved-intelligent-dogs-being-the-secret-masters-of-huma

Comment: Welcome to Scifi.SE. Do you remember the name of the weekly you read this story in perhaps?

Comment: What language _did_ you read it in?

Comment: @fez Thank you. The name of the weekly is Politikin Zabavnik. The story was published sometime between 1988. and 1992.

Comment: @DavidW Serbian, in a magazine called Politikin Zabavnik. The magazine itself wasn't really SF / Fantasy oriented, they just had this one or two page section for stories.

Answer (score 5):

Found it. The story is called **A Pet**, and the author is Zoran Jaksic. The setting was somewhat different from what I remembered - there's a short walk in the park, and the rest of the story does take place in a closed environment. Oh, and the pet was a poodle.

The automated translation can be found [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sr&tl=en&u=https://www.rastko.rs/knjizevnost/fantastika/jaksic_nikadorski.html%23_Toc465831973).

Comment: Ah, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. For self-answers, you won't be able to accept until 48 hours after asking the question, but we still want you to do it so it's marked as answered.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Will do, thank you.

Comment: And is it one of the works on http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?277012?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, it's not on that list. Judging by the link I posted, the author has more short stories out there.

Comment: :) Ah well, if you have the inclination, you can always suggest additions to the ISFDB. I'm afraid that, due to its volunteer nature, it's a bit heavily weighted towards English, with other languages falling off.

Comment: Ah, no worries. Makes sense, I guess.

Comment: @FelixTheDog - Glad to see you found what you were looking for! Please do stick around, maybe someone will ask a question you'll be able to answer!